# Uniform distribution with random on iris

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I have to randomly select 30 data points uniformly. The part that confuses me is why we are checking `if random.random() <= p` ? Can anyone explain?

```
from sklearn import datasets
import random
iris = datasets.load_iris()
d = iris.data

# sample 30 points uniform randomly from 150 points dataset
n = 150
m = 30
p = m/n

lst = []
for i in range(0, n):
    if random.random() <= p:
        lst.append(d[i,:])
```

Comment: This is a maths problem, not a programming issue. It's setting a threshold of acceptance on whether or not you're going to pick a particular value. You have 150 samples, you want 30, as you traverse your samples you want a 30/150 probability of adding it to your set.

Comment: I'd be curious, according to the author of the code is the goal to select exactly 30 elements, or select approximately 30 elements? This will rarely give you exactly 30 (~8% of the time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `p` represents the probability of an element being selected.

As there are `150` total elements, and `30` elements need selecting, the probability of selecting one element is `30/150`. This is set to `p`.

Each element is then iterated over and if the result of `random.random()` (between `0` and `1`) is greater than `p`, than that element is selected (I assume this; I do not fully know your dataset).

On average, this should give about `30` elements.

Comment: Note that this is not adding to the *explanation* of the code, but I'd like to point out that this is not a reliable way for selecting `30` elements at all. On average, `30` elements will be selected, but on one specific run, `28` or `34` whatever may be chosen which may not be desired. A better method would be to use `random.randint` to select `30` random indexes between `0` and `150` and use these to select *exactly* 30 elements.

Comment: I was considering this too. I don't think there's anything inherently more uniform by the approach the OP is using?

Comment: I was going to say something similar to this. This is a great way to _not_ select exactly 30 elements. In my testing, running this code >100,000 times, you get exactly 20% of the elements ~8% of the time.

Comment: @G.Anderson Nice